# Is it possible to "Center" Align Data Field in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to if it is possible to "Center" Align the content of a Data Field in Docusign?

I have a template with document in which for one value it is required to be CENTER aligned.

Any reference would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any "alignment" property for DocuSign tabs -- I believe Text tab (Data Field) contents will always be rendered as left-aligned.  The fact that I don't see any alignment property in a Data Field's properties via the DocuSign UI seems to support this belief:

[image: DS properties]

Comment: Ahhh okay. It would be awesome if they have given the settings for Right / Left aligned.

Comment: Kim is correct, you can submit your suggestion [here](http://community.docusign.com/t5/Share-Your-Ideas-and-Vote-for-the-Best/idb-p/DocuSignIdeas) for others to upvote